# e to an integral as an infinite product via the definition of the integral

Tags: integration, limits, infinite-product, eulers-number-e

Is there a name for this relationship? I am having a hard time searching for it. I'm hoping I've typed this up correctly, it's my first question here.

$x_k^\star$ is for instance $\frac{k \cdot h}{n}$

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left[\prod \limits_{k=0}^n\left(1+f(x_k^\star)\cdot\frac{h}{n}\right)\right] = e^{\int \limits_{0}^hf(x) \, dx}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way your $x_k^\star$ behave (they actually depend on $n$ as well as $k$), this will usually not be an "infinite product".

An interesting related subject studies ["product integrals"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) like the left side of your equation.

Comment: Ah! I believe that what I was trying to convey is exactly what is shown as the Type 1 (Volterra Integral) there.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, use that
$$ \ln\prod_{k=0}^n(1+ a_k)=\sum_{k=0}^n\ln(1+a_k)$$
together with $\ln(1+ a_k)\approx a_k$ when $a_k\approx 0$. (One has to make the latter a bit more explicit though)